# Using Categorical Predictor Variables in sci-kit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, categorical-data

Basic question here:

I'm trying to implement a simple classification model for credit card default where I just use `model.fit`, `model.predict` on my input data. However, that input data contains both categorical data (like demographic information like Age, Married or Not, Education level) and continuous data (like credit balances).

```
data.info()
```

```html
<div class="output"><div class="output_area"><div class="run_this_cell"></div><div class="prompt"></div><div class="output_subarea output_text output_stream output_stdout"><pre>&lt;class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'&gt;
Int64Index: 30000 entries, 1 to 30000
Data columns (total 24 columns):
LIMIT_BAL    30000 non-null float64
SEX          30000 non-null int64
EDUCATION    30000 non-null int64
MARRIAGE     30000 non-null int64
AGE          30000 non-null int64
PAY_1        30000 non-null int64
PAY_2        30000 non-null int64
PAY_3        30000 non-null int64
PAY_4        30000 non-null int64
PAY_5        30000 non-null int64
PAY_6        30000 non-null int64
BILL_AMT1    30000 non-null float64
BILL_AMT2    30000 non-null float64
BILL_AMT3    30000 non-null float64
BILL_AMT4    30000 non-null float64
BILL_AMT5    30000 non-null float64
BILL_AMT6    30000 non-null float64
PAY_AMT1     30000 non-null float64
PAY_AMT2     30000 non-null float64
PAY_AMT3     30000 non-null float64
PAY_AMT4     30000 non-null float64
PAY_AMT5     30000 non-null float64
PAY_AMT6     30000 non-null float64
default      30000 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(13), int64(11)
memory usage: 5.7 MB
</pre></div></div></div>
```

From my understanding, scikit-learn requires all data to be numerical and continuous or specifically coded as a categorical variable. The numerical part is not a problem since all of my data is coded numerically (like 0 for Married, 1 for not) but 3 of my variables (SEX, EDUCATION, and MARRIAGE) are nominal/ordinal and need to be encoded as categorical variables instead of int64 ones.

How do I use encode these 3 variables with scikit-learn's preprocessing module to properly feed these features into a model like Logistic Regression?

Thanks in advance, and please forgive the formatting (feel free to edit or recommend how I can properly include Jupyter Notebook output into a Stack Overflow post).

Comment: Where do you see the requirement that data be continuous? Are you talking about the difference between a classification vs a regression problem? Once it is numerically encoded, it is fit to be fed into the model. Have you tried, and what is the problem or error you encounter?

Comment: Hmm, I guess the issue is with the encouding then. Right now, all my features are encoded as float64 or int64, but I think I need to encode all the int64 ones to categories with [sklearn-preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing).

I got the requirement that data had to be continuous from Datacamp's course on Supervised Learning. But I also found on [scikit-learn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) that integer representations of categorical variables don't work.

Comment: That makes more sense! Since the categorical variables are already numeric, just use the built-in [One-Hot encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to transform the variables into one-hot columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categorical features need more attention in feature engineering, because features like Age, date etc are difficult to encode. There are many ways to encode these features, by analyzing, domain-knowledge and many more.

There is a library **category_encoders**, which have many functionality to encode such features, by the use of statistics. More you can find [here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/).

Here, is another good [resource](https://www.kaggle.com/discdiver/category-encoders-examples), that will shows you the use of encoding method by an example.